# Horizontally center toggle button on mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a default Bootstrap nav setup in my Wordpress site

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>
            </div>           
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --> 
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right"> 
                <?php /* Primary navigation */
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu' => 'top_menu',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
            </div>
    </nav>
</div><!-- /row -->
```

I want the 'toggle' button to center horizontally and the navbar-brand to dissappear on mobile screens. (I'm going to add a jumbotron that only shows on mobile)

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.navbar-brand { display:none; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {text-align: center;}

...
```

I bringing in Bootstrap CDN prior to my CSS. My css doesn't work, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to specify your CSS at different screen sizes. Using the default Bootstrap size for mobile which is 767px and below and thinking in a mobile-first mentality:

```
.navbar-brand { display: none; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {text-align: center;}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-brand { display: block; }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {text-align: left;}

}
```

Comment: my apologies I do have that, My issue is that code i tried doesn't work. I will update my question, I didn't realize it wasn't included